# Android Configuration with name 'kapt' not found

Tags: android

I'm trying to use `Realm` database on my project i add

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.9.0"
```

to `build.gradle`

and

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

to module `build.gradle`, after click on sync i get this error:

```
Configuration with name 'kapt' not found.
```

`build.gradle` content:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.9'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.9.0"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

`build.gradle` module content:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled = true
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath false
            }
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

/* IMPORTANT : 
 * Be careful when update dependencies, different version library may caused error */

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    // google maps library ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'

    // google gson --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
    // third party dependencies 
    implementation 'com.github.smart-fun:TabStacker:1.0.4'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'      // add this line
    implementation 'com.fatboyindustrial.gson-jodatime-serialisers:gson-jodatime-serialisers:1.2.0'

    implementation 'com.github.armcha:AutoLinkTextView:0.3.0'
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0"
    annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0"

    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.15'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.15'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.10'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.10'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
    implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    implementation 'com.birbit:android-priority-jobqueue:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.onehilltech.concurrent:concurrent-android:0.8.1'
    implementation 'com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    implementation 'com.blankj:utilcode:1.22.10'
    implementation 'com.ncapdevi:frag-nav:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.8'
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.8'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation project(path: ':bottomsheet-commons')
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'

    kapt "io.realm:realm-annotations-processor:5.9.0"
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    cleanedAnnotations
    compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
}
```

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I had the same issue but I was lacking the line

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

After briefly trying, I found that adding the line **before** `apply plugin: 'realm-android'` works for me.

In my case the top part of my working build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

So please try the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

And if that doesn't work, try moving the line directly above the apply realm plugin line (i.e. below the hugo and bintray plugins).

Comment: Realm.io should have this instruction on their website. It is a non-sense that we have to ask things around here and find solutions.

Comment: I loved that `before` word :P

Comment: Didn't notice and used `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` which broke my build, make sure to use `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` if it's an application

Comment: with newer versions of android studio place in inside plugins section. plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

Answer (score 3):

Try putting:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

before:

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

I had the same issue and this worked for me

Answer (score 3):

If you're using some version of Android Studio ArcticFox, there's a new way of declaring these plugins. It goes like this on your build.gradle (app level)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'realm-android'
}

android {
    ....
}

realm {
    syncEnabled = true
}

dependencies {
    ....
}
```

And don't forget the build.gradle (project level)

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.0"
ext.realm_version = '10.8.1'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:$realm_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

was facing the same issue, project was on git i just hit the pull and there was the issue that Kapt() not found .

Fixed: clear cache and restart/add
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' at the top/ sync project